Expo EAS build failed suddenly
EAS build for android failing. It was working fine. But suddenly failed to build while yarn install dependencies
NB: No changes were made after the successful build-in of package.json. The project runs fine locally.
Eas build errors -
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
error /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/babel-plugin-react-compiler: Command failed.
Exit code: 127
Command: ./scripts/link-react-compiler-runtime.sh
Arguments: 
Directory: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/babel-plugin-react-compiler
Output:
/bin/sh: 1: ./scripts/link-react-compiler-runtime.sh: not found
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
yarn install exited with non-zero code: 127

Complete eas build logs-
Running "yarn install" in /home/expo/workingdir/build directory
yarn install v1.22.21
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning @babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from@7.18.9: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-export-namespace-from instead.
warning @expo/config-plugins > glob@7.1.6: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
warning @expo/config-plugins > glob > inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
warning expo > @expo/config > glob@7.1.6: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
warning expo > @expo/cli > glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
warning expo > @expo/cli > glob > inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
warning expo > @expo/metro-config > glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
warning expo > @expo/config > sucrase > glob@7.1.6: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
warning expo > @expo/cli > npm-package-arg > osenv@0.1.5: This package is no longer supported.
warning expo > babel-preset-expo > @react-native/babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead.
warning expo > babel-preset-expo > @react-native/babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-numeric-separator instead.
warning expo > babel-preset-expo > @react-native/babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.21.0: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining instead.
warning expo > babel-preset-expo > @react-native/babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-object-rest-spread instead.
warning expo > babel-preset-expo > @react-native/babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-catch-binding instead.
warning expo > babel-preset-expo > @react-native/babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-async-generator-functions instead.
warning expo > babel-preset-expo > @react-native/babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator instead.
warning expo > babel-preset-expo > @react-native/babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-logical-assignment-operators instead.
warning expo > @expo/cli > tempy > del > rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
warning expo > @expo/cli > @react-native/dev-middleware > @rnx-kit/chromium-edge-launcher > rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
warning expo > @expo/cli > tempy > del > rimraf > glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
warning expo > babel-preset-expo > @react-native/babel-preset > @react-native/babel-plugin-codegen > @react-native/codegen > glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
warning expo > babel-preset-expo > @react-native/babel-preset > @react-native/babel-plugin-codegen > @react-native/codegen > jscodeshift > @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead.
warning expo > babel-preset-expo > @react-native/babel-preset > @react-native/babel-plugin-codegen > @react-native/codegen > jscodeshift > @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.21.0: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining instead.
warning expo > babel-preset-expo > @react-native/babel-preset > @react-native/babel-plugin-codegen > @react-native/codegen > jscodeshift > @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator instead.
warning expo > babel-preset-expo > @react-native/babel-preset > @react-native/babel-plugin-codegen > @react-native/codegen > jscodeshift > temp > rimraf@2.6.3: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
warning expo > babel-preset-expo > @react-native/babel-preset > @react-native/babel-plugin-codegen > @react-native/codegen > jscodeshift > temp > rimraf > glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
warning react-native > @react-native/community-cli-plugin > querystring@0.2.1: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
warning metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-async-generator-functions instead.
warning metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead.
warning metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator instead.
warning metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-numeric-separator instead.
warning metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-object-rest-spread instead.
warning metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-catch-binding instead.
warning metro-react-native-babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.21.0: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining instead.
warning patch-package > rimraf@2.7.1: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
warning patch-package > rimraf > glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "react-native > @react-native/codegen@0.74.87" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/preset-env@^7.1.6".
warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > @react-native/babel-preset > @react-native/babel-plugin-codegen > @react-native/codegen > jscodeshift@0.14.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/preset-env@^7.1.6".
warning "expo-splash-screen > @expo/prebuild-config@7.0.8" has unmet peer dependency "expo-modules-autolinking@>=0.8.1".
warning " > react-native-flash-message@0.2.1" has unmet peer dependency "prop-types@^15.0 || ^16.0".
warning "react-native-phone-number-input > react-native-country-picker-modal > @callstack/react-theme-provider@3.0.3" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.3.0".
warning "react-native-phone-number-input > react-native-country-picker-modal > modal-react-native-web@0.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@16.x.x".
warning "react-native-phone-number-input > react-native-country-picker-modal > modal-react-native-web@0.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-art@16.x.x".
warning "react-native-phone-number-input > react-native-country-picker-modal > modal-react-native-web@0.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@16.x.x".
warning "react-native-phone-number-input > react-native-country-picker-modal > modal-react-native-web@0.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react-native-web@0.9.x".
warning "react-native-render-html > @native-html/transient-render-engine@11.2.3" has unmet peer dependency "@types/react-native@*".
warning "react-native-render-html > @native-html/transient-render-engine > @native-html/css-processor@1.11.0" has unmet peer dependency "@types/react-native@*".
warning " > react-simple-form-validator@0.3.1" has unmet peer dependency "dayjs@>=1.10.7".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
error /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/babel-plugin-react-compiler: Command failed.
Exit code: 127
Command: ./scripts/link-react-compiler-runtime.sh
Arguments: 
Directory: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/babel-plugin-react-compiler
Output:
/bin/sh: 1: ./scripts/link-react-compiler-runtime.sh: not found
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.


I'm having the same issue with same code that worked yesterday. Seems like it has to do with the update mentioned.
There seems to be a workaround if you have a yarn.lock file.
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/31150#issuecomment-2399192691
I cannot try the fix since i removed my lock file in troubleshooting.
Edit; I managed to get it working by adding
"resolutions": {
 "**/babel-plugin-react-compiler": "0.0.0-experimental-ca8e0be-20240916"
},

to my package.json, removing node-modules and running yarn install.

Yees. It works.  Thank you man

npm registry updated, so we don't need to do anything and everything's back to normal... let's call it a day...

I encountered the same issue (I use npm install instead).
npm install
npm error code 127
npm error path /Users/kli/workspace/expoApp2/node_modules/babel-plugin-react-compiler
npm error command failed
npm error command sh -c ./scripts/link-react-compiler-runtime.sh
npm error sh: ./scripts/link-react-compiler-runtime.sh: No such file or directory
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/kli/.npm/_logs/2024-10-08T08_32_06_752Z-debug-0.log

I created the project with npx create-expo-app --template blank expoApp2, during creation, 127 error happened:
npx create-expo-app --template blank expoApp2
✔ Downloaded and extracted project files.
> npm install
npm warn deprecated osenv@0.1.5: This package is no longer supported.
npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-numeric-separator instead.
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator instead.
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead.
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-catch-binding instead.
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-logical-assignment-operators instead.
npm warn deprecated rimraf@2.6.3: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.21.0: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining instead.
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-async-generator-functions instead.
npm warn deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated querystring@0.2.1: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-object-rest-spread instead.
npm warn deprecated glob@7.1.6: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@7.1.6: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@7.1.6: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm error code 127
npm error path /Users/kli/workspace/expoApp2/node_modules/babel-plugin-react-compiler
npm error command failed
npm error command sh -c ./scripts/link-react-compiler-runtime.sh
npm error sh: ./scripts/link-react-compiler-runtime.sh: No such file or directory
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/kli/.npm/_logs/2024-10-08T08_38_27_326Z-debug-0.log
Something went wrong installing JavaScript dependencies. Check your npm logs. Continuing to create the app.
Error: npm install exited with non-zero code: 127

✅ Your project is ready!

To run your project, navigate to the directory and run one of the following npm commands.

- cd expoApp2
- npm run android
- npm run ios
- npm run web

It's wired that if I used expo init expoApp3 to create a project, and later chose blank in the workflow:

then everything goes well...
npm/npx ver: 10.9.0
expo ver: 6.3.10
expo --version
WARNING: The legacy expo-cli does not support Node +17. Migrate to the new local Expo CLI: https://blog.expo.dev/the-new-expo-cli-f4250d8e3421.
6.3.10

I think the node_modules folder can't be created for some unknown reason, so there is no further script/command could be called.

app.json

{
  "expo": {
    "name": "expoApp2",
    "slug": "expoApp2",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}


package.json

{
  "name": "expoapp2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~51.0.28",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}

Latest Update
Just resolved! As npm registry updated, I found some @babel/xxx modules resolved, e.g.,:
    "node_modules/@babel/generator": {
      "version": "7.25.7",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/generator/-/generator-7.25.7.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-5Dqpl5fyV9pIAD62yK9P7fcA768uVPUyrQmqpqstHWgMma4feF1x/oFysBCVZLY5wJ2GkMUCdsNDnGZrPoR6rA==",
      "license": "MIT",
      "dependencies": {
        "@babel/types": "^7.25.7",
        "@jridgewell/gen-mapping": "^0.3.5",
        "@jridgewell/trace-mapping": "^0.3.25",
        "jsesc": "^3.0.2"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=6.9.0"
      }
    },

Finally...let's call it a day :-)

Eas should handle create node_modules  for eas build that requires no permission

Just resolved, as npm registry updated, I found some @babel/xxx modules resolved, e.g.,  "node_modules/@babel/generator": {
"version": "7.25.7",
"resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/generator/-/generator-7.25.7.tgz",
"integrity": "sha512-5Dqpl5fyV9pIAD62yK9P7fcA768uVPUyrQmqpqstHWgMma4feF1x/oFysBCVZLY5wJ2GkMUCdsNDnGZrPoR6rA==",
"license": "MIT",
"dependencies": {
"@babel/types": "^7.25.7",
"@jridgewell/gen-mapping": "^0.3.5",
"@jridgewell/trace-mapping": "^0.3.25",
"jsesc": "^3.0.2"
},
...
